# Converting List of elements in a RDD to a float pyspark

Tags: python, lambda, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to convert all elements in a list inside a RDD to a float. This is what I did: 
`RDD.map(lambda line:line.encode("ascii", "ignore").strip().split()).map(convertToFloat)` and convert to float looks like this:

```
 def convertToFloat(lines):
        returnedLine = []    
        for x in lines:
            returnedLine.append(float(x))        
        return returnedLine
```

But this runs too slow. Is there a way we can replace the map(convertToFloat) part with a lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not using lambda but rather *list comprehension*

```
def convertToFloat(lines):
    returnedLine = [float(x) for x in lines]
```

and if you *really* want lambda on top:

```
convertToFloat = lambda lines: [float(x) for x in lines]
```

but the speed gain comes from the list comprehension, not from the lambda.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Jean!!